# Google OAuth2 remove prompt

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to make Google OAuth application following [this example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2Draft10). My application is a web application and I want to replace following code:

```
System.out.println("Paste this url in your browser: " + authorizeUrl);

// Wait for the authorization code
System.out.println("Type the code you received here: ");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String authorizationCode = in.readLine();
```

Because it prompts to enter code I get after hitting `authorizeUrl` URL in browser. I want to remove this prompt and application should go without prompt getting required `code` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove prompt Spring MVC helps.

Redirect to that URL with `RedirectView` and set call back URL back to your applications current URL/page and get `CODE` parameter from request.

Answer (score 2):

Users have to grant access the first time they access your application - unless you're using two-legged OAuth and have a Google Apps admin to grant access to their entire domain. A user only has to authorize your application once, though. When you get back the response from the OAuth server, you should store the refresh token. The refresh token can then be used to request new access tokens after the old one expires. The refresh token never expires but can be revoked by the user; if that happens you would need to prompt them again.

You should read up on Google's OAuth implementation at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer. You can also use [the OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to examine the request and refresh flow in a live environment.

Comment: Thanks. After getting access token what to do with it. If I need to call goggleAPI then how? Can you hint any example. I am using Spring MVC for my Web Application.

Comment: The access token is sent in all authorized requests as part of the value of an "Authorization" header. The process is detailed under "Calling a Google API" in the first link I provided.